# Blender sculpting brush shows odd

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]

[image]

my brush is a normal circle in front of the object. but it became very long when I move to the side.

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: Notice how the scale is not 1,1,1 in the right side of your screen. Hit CTRL + A > Scale to apply the transform

Comment: Thank you very much.